# vault read secrets with python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to read secrets from vault using python.  Having some security issues:

I can confirm authentication is working

```
 client = hvac.Client(url=vault_url)
 client.auth.aws.iam_login(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, credentials.token)

 print(client.is_authenticated())
```

but reading a secret is not working:

I tried:

```
response = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version( path='kv-v2/lambda-function')
```

and:

```
response = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version( path='lambda-function')
```

and:

```
secret = 'kv-v2/lambda-function'

mount_point, secret_path = secret.split('/', 1)
response = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version(
    mount_point=mount_point, path=secret_path)
```

all yield

```
[ERROR] Forbidden: 1 error occurred:
* permission denied
```

the following policy is in place:

```
path "kv-v2/lambda-function/*" {
    capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

but I've also tried:

```
path "kv-v2/data/lambda-function/*" {
    capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

the policy is linked to the auth:

```
vault write auth/aws/role/role... \
    auth_type=iam \
    bound_iam_principal_arn="arn:.."
    policies=lambda-function \
    ttl=5m
```

and in the Vault console I can read the secret like this:

```
vault kv get kv-v2/lambda-function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a bit further experimentation it turns out that the correct policy is:

```
path "kv-v2/+/lambda-function*" {
    capabilities = ["read","list"]
}
```

and the correct hvac calls are:

```
   response = client.secrets.kv.v2.list_secrets(
                        mount_point='kv-v2', path='/')

   response = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version(
                 mount_point='kv-v2', path='/lambda-function')
```

All dandy now.

Comment: Hello I have just tried using this code but still getting error. Any idea how to solve this?

```
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(url='https://vault.abc.com:1100/')
response = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version(path='/secrets/secret/show/ab/ss/dd')
```             


Error-

raise_for_error raise exceptions.Forbidden(message, errors=errors, method=method, url=url) hvac.exceptions.Forbidden: 1 error occurred: * permission denied